# CountIf criteria compare dates

Tags: excel, excel-2007, countif

I am trying to create a CountIf function from range `C2:C1700` where the criteria is `00/01/1900 or 0`. The cells in my range are all formulas that retrieve a date. (0 if cell is blank, 4235 if cell is correct). I am using a formatting to display the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` (if that makes a difference).

```
Cell: C2 = [path]Sheet1!X2 - Value = 0 
Cell: C3 = [path]Sheet1!X3 - Value = 4235
Cell: C4 = [path]Sheet1!X4 - Value = 0
Cell: C5 = [path]Sheet1!X5 - Value = 0
```

Now in my sheet I would like to create a `=COUNTIF('[path]Orders'!$C$2:$C$1700;0)`, but I can't seem to get the correct formula. Either `0` or `#VALUE`. I have also tried `TEXT()` and `DATE()` to format my criteria, but none worked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the formula you need, this is an array formula so you have to finish it off by pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

```
=SUM(IF($C$2:$C$1700=0,1,0))
```

To check for additional conditions such as blanks just add nested IFs like so:

```
=SUM(IF($C$2:$C$1700=0,1,IF($C$2:$C$1700="",1,0)))
```

Comment: You need to remove `:A3` and then it works ;) Do you know whether that could hold a check for blank rows too? I just tried adding an `AND`function but that failed.

Comment: Added example to cope with blanks